# database query hangs to DB2 server, using tomcat connection pool in java code

Tags: java, tomcat, db2, jndi, connection-pooling

I have developed a web application and using Tomcat connection pool,Java code is triggering query to DB2 server, sometimes it runs fine and return the result, but sometime it hangs i.e. the query will run continuously without any clue. Then i have to restart the Tomcat server which resolves the problem and give successfull data from database, I'm using JNDI and have configured the paramaters in server.xml of tomcat server(6.x).

configuration in web.xml of application's war file:-
`<resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection Pool </description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/abcd</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource </res-type>
        <res-auth>Container </res-auth>
    </resource-ref>`

configuration in context.xml apache tomcat server:-
`<ResourceLink global="jdbc/abcd" name="jdbc/abcd" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />`

configuration in server.xml:-
`<Resource name="jdbc/abcd" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="zzzzz" password="zzzzz" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" url="jdbc:db2://IP:50000/MYDB" />`

I've not configured any additional parameters like minIdle,maxIdle,maxWait and maxActive.

Please let me know about correct procedure of configuration which parameter i've to change in order to handle the connection properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "handling the connection properly". You could set the commandTimeout datasource property to terminate the query after some time if that's what you want. However, I have a feeling that the problem is on the database size. For example, you suffer from lock conflicts and the `locktimeout` parameter in the database is set to infinity, which causes some connections to wait forever. You probably need to talk to your DBA.

Comment: Thanks Mustaccio, but if its problem with database, then how come tomcat restart is resolving the issue. Issue is like, we got an exception after creation of connection object and statement object and at stmt.executeQuery("Query"); the code broke down and goes to catch block, their unfortunately i've not closed connection object(con.close();) on error, after that if application is trying to connect to database for the second time then its waiting for long without going to catch block.

Comment: It might go like this: Connection A holds a lock. Connection B wants to update the locked record and waits forever. You restart Tomcat. Both connections are terminated, transactions rolled back, locks released. Next time it so happens that connection B gets there first and, since there's no lock, updates the record.

Comment: DBA told they didn't encountered any lockout event.`